# How to autorun methods in a class?

Tags: python, oop

i have class A *{1st stage}*

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
    def print1(self):
        print(self.arg1 +' World!')
    def print2(self):
        print(self.arg2 + ' is smart')
```

I'm identify arguments: *{2nd stage}*

```
hello = 'Hello'
cat = 'Cat'
a = A(hello, cat)
```

if i will use *{3rd stage}*

```
a.print1()
a.print2()
```

i will get *{4th stage}*

```
Hello World!
Cat is smart
```

My question is how i can call my methods by autorun? I mean without *{3rd stage}*. To just identify `arguments` and `object` of `class` and get the `output`

Comment: `self.print1(); self.print2()` inside `__init__`…?

Comment: What do you mean by "autorun"? When should it happen?

Comment: @martineau i mean launch of `print1` and `print2`, @deceze made a right descision

Answer (score 2):

you can call your methods in __init__

```
def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self.print1()
        self.print2()
```